# reading Data from Parsed XML

Tags: php, xml, arrays, xml-parsing, photobucket

I have an XML file that is returned by an API.i want to get specfic Data out of it.I had converted the XML into array by  `$xml = simpleXMLToArray(simplexml_load_string($response));`
$response is the XML.$xml is the array that have all the XML data.I want to extract data out of it but its not working.

```
foreach($xml['conetent']['album']['media'] as $media)
    {
        //var_dump($media);
      echo $media;
    }
```

Comment: better to debug $xml using `var_dump($xml)` to find out what is the structure of multi-dimension array

Comment: @Mark it doesn't display everything inside the array..It hides some info by putting "..."

Comment: so try using `print_r` ?

Comment: It display the data but unable to even read that..Unable to read the structure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine here once you correct the spelling of 'conetent' to 'content'

Edit:

So with the update from your question, how about this:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//content/album') as $album)
{
    print "Album: ";
    foreach($album->attributes() as $key => $value)
        print "\t".$key." = ".$value."\n";
    foreach($album->xpath('album') as $subalbum)
    {
        print "\tSub album:\n";
        foreach($subalbum->attributes() as $key => $value)
            print "\t\t".$key." = ".$value."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add what it was you wanted to extract? I agree that it would be easier to look with XPath and do a loop through all media nodes, picking the information you want, but without knowing what you want the output to be, it is hard to say

Comment: I want to extract album and subalbum but with proper hierarchy?

Comment: it doesnt traverse the array.It show the same album name and its attributes four times

Comment: Your answer is right wood just a small change that please chane $album to $subalbum

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you have two levels of album tags.  It would probably be easier not to use simpleXMLToArray() but just search for your media with [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php):

```
$result= $xml->xpath('//media');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo '/media: ',$node,"\n";
}
```

Comment: Good Idea but it only display /media: /media: /media: /media: /media: